# Why do I still get an error about publishing changes from background threads after marking my ViewModel class with @MainActor?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view model class for `ContentView` called `ViewModel` defined as:

```
extension ContentView {
  @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var exerciseList: [Exercise]
  
    init() {
      exerciseList = [Exercise]()
    }
}
```

In `ContentView` I have:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

  var body: some View {

    List {
      ForEach(viewModel.exerciseList) { exercise in
        Text(exercise.ExerciseName)
      }
    }
    .onAppear {
      await Api.getExerciseListWithHash(hashString: "a") { result in
        switch result {
          case .success(let exs):
            //DispatchQueue.main.async {
              viewModel.exerciseList = exs.ExerciseList //error occurs here
            //}
          case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The code actually runs and the list loads but the error message is delivered in purple at runtime. Adding the `DispatchQueue.main.async` line eliminates the error but causes the list to never load. I also tried adding a setter function to `ViewModel` thinking that would fall under the `@MainActor` wrapper, but it produces the same error message.

Comment: Your method `Api.getExerciseListWithHash(completion:)` isn't using structured concurrency as the result is being returned in a completion handler. `@MainActor` only works when used with Swift concurrency. What does your `Api.getExerciseListWithHash(completion:)` look like?

Comment: @Paul.s what is "structured concurrency"?

Comment: @Paul.s it calls a web api and returns a response object containing a list of Exercise objects. I used result as I'd read that it was ideal for asynchronous network calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to convert your api call from a completion handler based method to using `async` without seeing the code it's hard to suggest how that might look but essentially you want your API to change from:

```swift
func getExerciseListWithHash(
    hashString: String, 
    completion: @escaping (Result<ExsType, Error>) -> Void
) async { ... }
```

to

```swift
func getExerciseListWithHash(hashString: String) async throws -> ExsType { ... }
```

Then your call site would end up looking like this

```swift
.onAppear {
    do {
        let exes = try await Api.getExerciseListWithHash(hashString: "a")
        await viewModel.exerciseList = exs.ExerciseList
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky but Apple demonstrate this pattern in the Meme Creator tutorial in the [Fetching Panda Data section](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/sample-apps/memecreator#Fetching-Panda-Data). Adapting your code to match would look something like this:

```
// note not @MainActor
// it's best not to name this class a ViewModel because in SwiftUI the View struct is the view model.
class ExerciseFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var exercises: [Exercise] = []
  
    func fetchExercises() async throws {
        // since class and func is not @MainActor this can run on background thread.
        let results = try await Api.getExerciseListWithHash(hashString: "a")
        // jump back to main thread.
        Task { @MainActor in
             self.exercises = results
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject private var fetcher = ExerciseFetcher()

  var body: some View {

    List {
      ForEach(fetcher.exercises) { exercise in
        Text(exercise.name)
      }
    }
    .task { // this runs when the screen appears and is cancelled when it disappears, you can also use task(id:) to restart when the id param changes.
      do {
          try await fetcher.fetchExercises()
      }
      catch {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
          // you could set a message on an @State var to display it.
      }
    }
  }
```